# Loading an Angular module from Jasmine unit test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, chutzpah

I'm trying to setup my Angular unit test in Visual Studio with Chutpah and Jasmine.

I get this error, and I'm not sure why:

This is the code to test in my timelineservice.js file (in my angular project, simplified for my first-test )

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('timelineService',
    [

        function timelineServiceInit(){

            return {
                exciteText: function (msg) {
                    return msg + '!!!';
                }
            };
        }
    ]
);
```

This is my unit test:

```
describe('basicService tests', function () {
    var myservicenaam;


    // excuted before each "it" is run.
    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.mock.module('myApp', []);
        var $injector = angular.injector(['myApp']);

        var myService = $injector.get('timelineService');
        myservicenaam = myService;
    });



    //it's removed 
});
```

What is weird (imho) is that when I debug, the code goes to the `'timelineservice.js'` file first, and then the module is not loaded (which is correct).
I thought the testcode would run first and at that point load the module.

In my testproject I have references to the angular files and the code files.

When I put the `angular.module('myApp', []);` code in the `timelineservice.js` file, it all works.

Comment: Your module declaration for your app looks like it's the setter pattern as opposed to the getter. I think it should be beforeEach(module('myApp'));

Comment: That did it, thanks!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer and you can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you are using a setter pattern instead of a getter pattern so your app doesn't properly load. Try the following declaration before your tests:

```
 beforeEach(module('myApp'));
```